# Problem with overlay last doesn't work:

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I hope you guys are fine! I've used this colorbox in one of my files but I edited it so it can be breakable by adding trivially the overlay keys, anyways here's my code and the result after compiling it :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{exo}[1][]{%
    enhanced, breakable, fonttitle=\large\bfseries,
    title=\raisebox{-2pt}{\textcolor{blue}{E}},
    left=\tcboxedtitlewidth,
    boxsep=0pt, top=2mm, right=2mm, bottom=2mm+0.7\baselineskip,
    sharp corners, colback=white, colbacktitle=blue, frame hidden,  opacityback=.5,
    pad before break=-0.7\baselineskip,
    before upper = {\begingroup
        \large\bfseries\textcolor{blue}{xercice }
        \textcolor{red}{\thetcbcounter} \quad\endgroup},
    attach boxed title to top left={
        xshift=2pt,
        yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight+1.5pt-2mm},
    boxed title style={
        empty, left=0mm, right=0mm, top=0mm, bottom=0mm, boxsep=2pt},
    underlay boxed title={
        \path[fill=red] (title) circle (\tcboxedtitleheight/2);},
    overlay unbroken={
        \coordinate[xshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2,
        yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight-0.7\baselineskip] (nw) at (frame.north west);
        \node (sw) [circle, fill=red, inner sep=2pt,
        xshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2, yshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2]
        at (frame.south west) {};
        \draw[blue, line cap=round, line width=2pt,
        dash pattern=on 0pt off 4\pgflinewidth] (nw) -- (sw);},
    overlay first={
        \coordinate[xshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2,
        yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight-0.7\baselineskip] (nw) at (frame.north west);
        \coordinate[xshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2,
        yshift=0.7\baselineskip] (sw) at (frame.south west);
        \draw[blue, line cap=round, line width=2pt,
        dash pattern=on 0pt off 4\pgflinewidth] (nw) -- (sw);}
    overlay last = {
       \coordinate[xshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2,
        yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight-0.7\baselineskip] (nw) at (frame.north west);
        \node (sw) [circle, fill=red, inner sep=2pt,
        xshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2, yshift=\tcboxedtitlewidth/2]
        at (frame.south west) {};
        \draw[blue, line cap=round, line width=2pt,
        dash pattern=on 0pt off 4\pgflinewidth] (nw) -- (sw);
    } ,#1}


\begin{document}

\vspace*{12cm}


\begin{exo}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]
\end{exo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see in the picture above, the second part of the box isn't framed as I want to. Any ideas or thoughts on how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: A comma `,` is missing between`overlay first` definition and `overlay last`.